# Search an array using massivejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postgresql, massivejs

I'm trying to construct a query on an array using massivejs, but it keeps telling me the operator is unsupported.

This query works:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE data->'items' @> '[{"foo": "bar"}]';
```

where `data` is a jsonb field and `items` is an array of objects. My massivejs query is:

```
{ 'data #>> {items} @>': '[{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }]' }
```

but massive tells me the `@>` operator doesn't exist.

I realize I can execute raw SQL, but I'm building up a query with paging, sorting, and other query conditions, so I'd rather not rebuild all that if I can avoid it.

Is there a mistake in my query? Is this something massivejs even supports?

Comment: This should be supported as of version 2.2.0, released at the beginning of 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `massivejs` supports jsonb operators.

Your query is SQL-correct. And I guess that you'll have to do raw SQL on this one.

I just read the API docs and it goes in my direction but *I might be overlooking something*.

Comment: It has partial jsonb support, but this is a grey area. And our usage isn't compatible with `findDoc`.